# w Devise, how to allow a SignIn user to sign in as another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My app auto-creates a guest user account. The problem there is that the guest user may want to sign-in to the real account.

I therefore want to let users Sign In that are already signed_in? according to devise.

While I can render the form, if I submit the signin form, devise kicks it to a redirect:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-19 18:21:45 -0700
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RE/xxx=", "user"=>{"email"=>"sally.jones@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 102 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 266ms
```

**Update**

I tried:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    Rails.logger.info 'XXXXX 2'
    super
    Rails.logger.info 'XXXXX 4'
  end

end
```

But devise seems to be kicking out the request before it even hits that method and the logger's aren't in the log file

Any ideas on how I can allow a signed_in user to sign in?

Comment: How were you able to render sign in page? Mine would say "You are already signed in." when I try to access /users/sign_in

Comment: if you think my answer is correct please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 6):

Devise has support for switching to another user using the sign_in method. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin. 
It also has the concept of Guest user: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Answer (score 3):

Well if you create an account automatically, does that mean your `current_{resource}` is gonna return an user? if so its normal that devise redirects you from sign_in and sign_up routes(if you see the source code there is a `prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication`).

That's to explain the redirect... now to solve your problem to have to extend the controllers and create a before filter with require authentication only for non guest users.

Take attention to this:

In https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb

there is the definition of require_no_authentication, which does a little bit more than verifying if your user is authenticated. so got add another before filter just for guest_users

For example:

P.S. Everywhere you read {resource} is the name of your model class. If User then user, if Profile then profile, attention to downcasing.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :require_no_authentication, :unless => :guest_user?, :only => [:new,:create, :cancel]
  before_filter :require_no_authentication_for_guests, :if => :guest_user?, :only => [:new,:create, :cancel]

  private

  def guest_user?
    current_{resource}.is_guest?
  end

  def require_no_authentication_for_guests
    assert_is_devise_resource!
  end 
end
```

On your model:

```
Class {resource}
  def is_guest?
    # here you put the code that distinguishes a guest user which should return true if its one>
  end
end
```

also need to change the routes file:

if your registrations controller is called like in the example and the if the resource is user

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions",
                                  :registrations => "registrations"}
```

Then you do the same on your sessions controller. by that I mean to apply the same before filters on a custom sessions controller.

Attention where you wanna apply the before filter and examine your requirements before.

Did it help?

Comment: Thanks but it seemed the custom RegistrationsController is never used during the request.

Comment: And how did you reach that conclusion? did you use the debugger? But I am sorry I forgot you have to configure your routes to use the custom controller. I will correct the answer

Comment: Also let me know which steps you took to test it and if using a debugger what seems to happen!

Answer (score 0):

you can do 2 actions. The first does sign out and redirect to the second one that  initiate a new seesion by another user

Comment: Right but I can't get access to def create. it isn't being called

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_website/blob/develop/app/controllers/users/impersonations_controller.rb

this functionality “impersonating another user”. an admin can go onto Admin::Users#index -> Find a user, and impersonate them. That is, sign into their account.need a button that posts to this action

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_website/blob/develop/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb#L11

```
def impersonate
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :impersonate, @user
    # Impersonate
    session[:impersonation_user_id] = current_user.id
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    warden.session_serializer.store(@user, Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(@user))
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end
```

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_authorization_check only: [:destroy]
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:impersonation_user_id])
    # Reset impersonation
    session[:impersonation_user_id] = nil
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    warden.session_serializer.store(@user, Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(@user))
    redirect_to(admin_users_path)
  end
end
```

Which uses devise, to set the session[:impersonation_user_id] so later you know you are impersonating another use, and then this warden.session_serializer.store which signs you in as a new user. If you close the tab. Reopen the tab. You will still be impersonating that user. Put a partial in the site (haml) to display an alert to the user on every page when they’re impersonating

```
  .bg-warning.d-print-none.text-center
    You are logged in as <strong>#{current_user}</strong>.
    = link_to 'click here', impersonate_path, 'data-method': :delete
    to return to your original account.
```

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_website/blob/develop/app/views/layouts/_impersonate.html.haml